# HOG cells and blocks

Tags: c++, image-processing

I'm trying to implement HOG for detecting hand gesture and I want to know if it's really necessary to divide the image into cells and blocks if my images have a very small size.

Comment: No it’s not. Just experiment with parameters till you get good results. The number of cells can be a parameter, which you can set to 1.